# How do I keep Blender from Freezing?

Tags: windows

I've searched around and it seems that most people aren't having problems with Blender on Windows 10, but I have a peculiar problem that is so easy to forget about and illogical that it ends up being annoying. 
*Problem:*
Whenever I am using Blender and then I minimize it use any other application or the desktop or the file explorer, Blender freezes (95% of the time, that's why it's illogical) and I have to force close it and open it back up again. This is simply uncomfortable... (Using Alt-tab does not freeze Blender for some reason.) I never had this problem on Windows 7, and when I upgraded to Windows 10, Blender immediately started having this problem. I updated Blender to 2.76b yesterday and it still has the same issue.

My computer's stats: Dell Precision M4800, Intel Core i7 2.50GHz, NVIDIA Quadro K2100M and Intel HD Graphics 4600, and 16 GB of RAM, on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.

I'm pretty sure this is not a hardware issue considering Blender works completely fine *except* for freezing up when I minimize it. I appreciate any help with this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: If you can reproduce this behavior fairly consistently, it may be worth filing a [bug report](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)

Comment: If anyone is still here, for me the problem was that Blender was in Full Screen - it did not crash if the window was not maximised. I also created a Bug Report: https://developer.blender.org/T51888

Comment: so... shortly after reporting, it got merged and I got a testfix and now it works ^^ https://developer.blender.org/T50856 - do your reports kids!